# baggedModel (fn="ets") function for weekly data?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

Is there any way to use the `baggedModel()` function in the R `forecast` package with the `ets` function argument for weekly data?

As the default `ets` can't handle data with a frequency greater than 24, `baggedModel` doesn't work for weekly data when the function chosen is ETS.

Without bagging, using `stlf()` works well for weekly data, but I would like to try bagging as well, if possible.

Sub-question: is there any difference between forecasts produced by the `forecast()` and `forecast.baggedModel()` functions when both are fed by a `baggedModel` object? For some reason, R cannot find the `forecast.baggedModel()` function, although all other functions in the `forecast` package work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as you have already found `ets()` does not work for high seasonal periods. The reason is that there are too many degrees of freedom associated with the seasonality --- with period 52, there would be 51 degrees of freedom just on the seasonal component which makes little sense.

Using forecast v8.5+, you can use the equivalent of `stlf()` with bagging as follows.

```
library(fpp2)

gasoline %>%
 baggedModel(fn=stlm, method='arima') %>%
 forecast(h=2*52) %>%
 autoplot()
```

`forecast()` is a method that calls the appropriate `forecast.xxx()` function depending on the class of its first argument. For the objects produced by `baggedModel`, is uses `forecast.baggedModel()`. This function is not exported, but you can see the code using `forecast:::forecast.baggedModel()`.

Comment: Thanks Rob! But code above doesn't work, it says "Error in match.arg(fn) : 'arg' should be one of “ets”, “auto.arima”. It seems `baggedModel` does not accept `stlm` function.   Also,  what is the difference between your code (where you use `baggedModel` with `method="arima"`) and `baggedmodel(fn="auto.arima")` ?

Comment: Use the github version of the package. `baggedModel(fn=stlm, method='arima')` fits an STL+ARIMA model. `baggedModel(fn='auto.arima')` fits an ARIMA model.